# Multi line conditional operator in string interpolation in C# fails

Tags: c#, conditional-operator, string-interpolation

```
var condition = false;
Foo($"String is {(condition ? "True" : "False")} works");
```

but

```
Foo($"String is {(condition ? "True" 
                            : "False")} fails");
```

I got compile error when I nicely format the conditional operator within my string interpolated statement?

Comment: use verbatim strings....   Foo($@"String is {(condition ? "True" 
                            : "False")}fails");

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I read about the 'solution' by using $@ instead which is weird because the conditional-operator is already needs to be separated by parenthesis and therefor its contents should not be interpreted as format specifiers anymore; using $@ makes also impossible to use format  literals like \t ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `@`

```
Foo($@"String is {(condition ? "True" 
                            : "False")} fails");
```

Comment: But how can I use string literals like \t then?

Comment: You can't. You have to choose one `\t` or `@`